# IE CSS bug: IMG original height affecting parent height

Tags: css, image, internet-explorer, size, flexbox

I've got a PARENT flexbox div (which is also part of a column flexbox):

```
div.flex_block {
        width:100%;
        flex: 1 1 auto;
        display:flex;
        flex-direction:row;
        align-items:center;
        justify-content:space-between;  
        padding-bottom:30px; 
}
```

It contains 2 children:

```
.flex_block  .content{
    max-width:none; /* override other code */
    flex: 0 1 50%;
}

.flex_block  .image{
    max-width:none; /* override other code */
    flex: 0 1 35%;
}
```

The first child has some text in it.
The second has an oversized image, that is set to 100% width, so it shrinks to its container.

```
.flex_block  .image img{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

It works as expected in Chrome, but in IE the original img's height seems to expand the PARENT container (even though it does shrink to fit its container).
If I set the img height, the problem is fixed. AUTO doesn't fix it.
I need this as a responsive design, obviously, so I don't wish to set the height in pixels.

Here is a visualisation of what happens:
[image]

I've also tried using inline elements with percentage widths instead of a flexbox, but the issue prevailed.

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution to this? I have similar issue right now that is driving me nuts. MS seems to have solved it with IE12 and IE13, but 11 is an issue.

Answer (score 1):

A *possible* solution to add to container:

```
flex-shrink: 0;
```

Or more specific to IE11:

```
-ms-flex-negative: 0;
```

This seems to have fixed my issue, but your results may vary.

I don't pretend to understand **why** it works, but it seems to be working for me. :)