# How to fix flex column height bug in IE

Tags: css, flexbox

In IE I am having a problem where my flex column is stretched for unknown reasons. I need the image height and width of each flex item to always be the same and also be responsive so I need them at 100%. I also need the flex footer to always be at the same level as the others, stuck to the bottom of the container regardless of whether the flex-name spans more than 1 line.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.flex-item-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid green;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 185px;
}

.link-spanner {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.flex-header {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}

.image-container {
  margin-top: 5px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.flex-item-name {
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item-wrapper">
      <a href='#' class="link-spanner"></a>
      <div class="flex-header">
        <div class="image-container">
          <img class="picture" src="http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/cartoons/super-mario/clip-art-super-mario-832109.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-name">Bingobongo Bongobingobongo</div>
      <div class="flex-footer">
        <button>submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item-wrapper">
      <a href='#' class="link-spanner"></a>
      <div class="flex-header">
        <div class="image-container">
          <img class="picture" src="http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/cartoons/super-mario/clip-art-super-mario-832109.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-name">Bingobongo Bongo</div>
      <div class="flex-footer">
        <button>submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item-wrapper">
      <a href='#' class="link-spanner"></a>
      <div class="flex-header">
        <div class="image-container">
          <img class="picture" src="http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/cartoons/super-mario/clip-art-super-mario-832109.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-name">Bingobongo Bongobingobongo</div>
      <div class="flex-footer">
        <button>submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a9kb5wdw/6/)

Comment: Tricky problem. You're not alone: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33351298/3597276

Comment: [Flexbox items do not vertically shrink when child images vertically shrink](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedbackdetail/view/891815)

Comment: @Michael_B Repeating the _bug fix_ seems to fix the issue when a wrapper is in between the flex container and the image

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In addition to this [post/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33351298/ie-css-bug-img-original-height-affecting-parent-height), if you add `min-height: 1px;` to both the `.flex-header` and the `.image-container` it will work in IE11 in your case as well ..

.. and I don't know why either, though according to this [<del>Microsoft bug report</del>](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedbackdetail/view/891815) [github post](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs/issues/75), it force IE to recalculate the sizes based on the image.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a9kb5wdw/7/)

```
.flex-header {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  min-height: 1px;
}

.image-container {
  margin-top: 5px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
}
```

*Actually, it also works if you add `-ms-flex-negative: 0;` to both the `.flex-header` and the `.image-container`*

Comment: You can in .image-container { flex-shrink: 0; }.

Answer (score 1):

On the parent element try to add:

```
display: flex;
align-items: stretch;
flex-direction: column;
min-height: 1px;
-ms-flex-negative: 0;
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar problem to yours: I have 2 flex items stacked in a column, and both have an image inside it, like this:

```
<article style="display: flex, flex-direction: column">
    <div id="topbar">
        <img src="..." id="topbar-banner">
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        <img src="..." id="background-img">
    </div>
<article>
```

Ideally, I want two columns to stack on top of each other, and each flex item to have the same height as its child. In all browsers except for IE, it works fine; but in IE, there is some white space below `#topbar-banner` and above the bottom of `#topbar`, and it gets bigger if you narrow down the page vertically.

I tried [LGSon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43027202/5827766), and added `-ms-flex-negative: 0` to `#topbar` (the div with unwanted white space in it), and it sovled my problem by removing the unwanted space. Like this:

```
<div id="topbar" style="-ms-flex-negative: 0">
```

Unfortunately, I can't find any official documentation on what `-ms-flex-negative` means, but I've seen people saying it's equivalent to `flex-shrink`.

I'm using IE11; according to Microsoft's [documentation on flexbox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh673531(v=vs.85).aspx), I'm not supposed to use any vendor prefix for IE11 now:

> Internet Explorer 11 no longer supports the Microsoft vendor prefix ("-ms-") version of the flexbox properties. You should instead use the non-prefixed names, which is preferred for better standards compliance and future compatibility.

On the other hand, this vendor prefix does fix my problem while no other did. So use it at your own discretion; might be worth it if no other alternatives exist.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to use Alignment-classes(.align-items-center or .align-self-center etc) , make sure you didn't use .my-auto class to vertically align center items it works perfectly in chrome but not in IE . Add class .align-items-center to flex container (.row) or .align-self-center to flex-children's (.col-*-* etc).

Answer (score 0):

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.flex-item-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid green;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 185px;
}

.link-spanner {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.flex-header {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}

.image-container {
  margin-top: 5px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.flex-item-name {
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item-wrapper">
      <a href='#' class="link-spanner"></a>
      <div class="flex-header">
        <div class="image-container">
          <img class="picture" src="http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/cartoons/super-mario/clip-art-super-mario-832109.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-name">Bingobongo Bongobingobongo</div>
      <div class="flex-footer">
        <button>submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item-wrapper">
      <a href='#' class="link-spanner"></a>
      <div class="flex-header">
        <div class="image-container">
          <img class="picture" src="http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/cartoons/super-mario/clip-art-super-mario-832109.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-name">Bingobongo Bongo</div>
      <div class="flex-footer">
        <button>submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item-wrapper">
      <a href='#' class="link-spanner"></a>
      <div class="flex-header">
        <div class="image-container">
          <img class="picture" src="http://www.picgifs.com/clip-art/cartoons/super-mario/clip-art-super-mario-832109.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-name">Bingobongo Bongobingobongo</div>
      <div class="flex-footer">
        <button>submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```